# How to run multiple python scripts simultaneously from a wrapper script in such a way that CPU utilization is maximized?

Tags: python, linux

I have to run about 200-300 python scripts daily having different arguments, for example:

```
python scripts/foo.py -a bla -b blabla ..
python scripts/foo.py -a lol -b lolol ..
....
```

Lets say I already have all these arguments for every script present inside a list, and I would like to concurrently execute them such that the CPU is always busy. How can I do so?'

**My current solution:**

script for running multiple processes:

```
    workers = 15
    for i in range(0,len(jobs),workers):
        job_string = ""
        for j in range(i,min(i+workers,len(jobs))):
            job_string += jobs[j] + " & "
        if len(job_string) == 0:
            continue
        print(job_string)
        val = subprocess.check_call("./scripts/parallelProcessing.sh '%s'" % job_string,shell=True)
```

scripts/parallelProcessing.sh (used in the above script)

```
echo $1
echo "running scripts in parallel"
eval $1
wait
echo "done processing"
```

**Drawback:**

I am executing K processes in a batch, and then another K and so on. But CPU cores utilization is much lower as the number of running processes keep reducing, and eventually only one process is running at a time (for a given batch). As a result, the time taken to complete all the processes is significant.

One simple solution is to ensure K processes are always running, i.e once the previous process gets completed, a new one must be scheduled. But I am not sure how to implement such a solution.

**Expectations:**

As the task is not very latency sensitive, I am looking forward to a simple solution which keeps CPU mostly busy.

**Note:** Any two of those processes can execute simultaneously without any concurrency issues. The host where these processes run has python2.

Comment: To confirm, you're sure the processes are CPU bound?

Comment: The processes are both CPU and memory bound, however the host has plenty of RAM (about 512 GB) so that won't be an issue. The memory is sufficient to handle about 30 such processes simultaneously.

Comment: If you're running the *same* script 200-300 times, perhaps you might like to refactor that script into a function and instead use python's multiprocessing module: in particular, Pool and the starmap method would be a good fit for what you want.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a technique I developed for calling many external programs using `subprocess.Popen`. In this example, I'm calling `convert` make JPEG images from DICOM files.

In short; it uses `manageprocs` to keep checking a list of running subprocesses. If one is finished, it is removed and a new one is started as long as unprocesses files remain. After that, the remaining processes are watched until they are all finished.

```
from datetime import datetime
from functools import partial
import argparse
import logging
import os
import subprocess as sp
import sys
import time


def main():
    """
    Entry point for dicom2jpg.
    """
    args = setup()
    if not args.fn:
        logging.error("no files to process")
        sys.exit(1)
    if args.quality != 80:
        logging.info(f"quality set to {args.quality}")
    if args.level:
        logging.info("applying level correction.")
    start_partial = partial(start_conversion, quality=args.quality, level=args.level)

    starttime = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
    logging.info(f"started at {starttime}.")
    # List of subprocesses
    procs = []
    # Do not launch more processes concurrently than your CPU has cores.
    # That will only lead to the processes fighting over CPU resources.
    maxprocs = os.cpu_count()
    # Launch and mange subprocesses for all files.
    for path in args.fn:
        while len(procs) == maxprocs:
            manageprocs(procs)
        procs.append(start_partial(path))
    # Wait for all subprocesses to finish.
    while len(procs) > 0:
        manageprocs(procs)
    endtime = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
    logging.info(f"completed at {endtime}.")


def start_conversion(filename, quality, level):
    """
    Convert a DICOM file to a JPEG file.

    Removing the blank areas from the Philips detector.

    Arguments:
        filename: name of the file to convert.
        quality: JPEG quality to apply
        level: Boolean to indicate whether level adustment should be done.
    Returns:
        Tuple of (input filename, output filename, subprocess.Popen)
    """
    outname = filename.strip() + ".jpg"
    size = "1574x2048"
    args = [
        "convert",
        filename,
        "-units",
        "PixelsPerInch",
        "-density",
        "300",
        "-depth",
        "8",
        "-crop",
        size + "+232+0",
        "-page",
        size + "+0+0",
        "-auto-gamma",
        "-quality",
        str(quality),
    ]
    if level:
        args += ["-level", "-35%,70%,0.5"]
    args.append(outname)
    proc = sp.Popen(args, stdout=sp.DEVNULL, stderr=sp.DEVNULL)
    return (filename, outname, proc)


def manageprocs(proclist):
    """Check a list of subprocesses for processes that have ended and
    remove them from the list.

    Arguments:
        proclist: List of tuples. The last item in the tuple must be
                  a subprocess.Popen object.
    """
    for item in proclist:
        filename, outname, proc = item
        if proc.poll() is not None:
            logging.info(f"conversion of “{filename}” to “{outname}” finished.")
            proclist.remove(item)
    # since manageprocs is called from a loop, keep CPU usage down.
    time.sleep(0.05)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've left out `setup()`; it's using `argparse` to deal with command-line arguments.

Here the thing to be processed is just a list of file names.
But it could also be (in your case) a list of tuples of script names and arguments.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Please confirm if I understand the code correctly. Partial object is used to call the method, which needs to be executed in parallel.   ManageProcs keeps running non stop until list of running processes == limit and everytime loop through the list and check if any of them have finished ( through poll() method )

Comment: @PriyeshAgarwal I use `partial` to "pre-fill" the `quality` and `level` arguments of `start_conversion`. The `manageprocs` function manages the list of processes. It is called repeatedly from two different loops.

Comment: Thanks, this should solve my problem.